# Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1'

Tags: c#, linq

Do you know how fix this error? It` s show error in this line "foreach (int s in itemColl)"

What I have to do?

> Error 1   Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to
>   'int' C:\Users\Rafal\Desktop\MVC ksiązka\moj
>   projekt\sklep\SportsStore.WebUI\Controllers\ProductController.cs  37  21  SportsStore.WebUI

```
var itemColl = from p in re.Kategorie
               where p.Nazwa == category
               select new
               {
                   p.Id_kat
               };


                foreach (int s in itemColl)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
```

Comment: A tip: Hover your mouse over `var` to see what the declared type is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are selecting `itemColl` with `new` keyword, defining an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), you can't apply `foreach` loop with `int` type. Your current query is returning something like `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`

Instead you may do:

```
var itemColl = from p in re.Kategorie
               where p.Nazwa == category
               select p.Id_Kat;
```

This will return `IEnumerable<int>` and that you can use in your current foreach loop.

But if you want to use your current query with selection on anonymous type, you have to modify your foreach loop with implicit type [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), and since your current query is returning an anonymous type object you may select the `Id_kat` from the object. Something like.

```
foreach (var s in itemColl)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Id_kat);
}
```

IMO, the second approach is not recommended because you are just returning an `int` type wrapped inside an anonymous type. Its better if you can change your query to return `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: Have you got idea what I have to do?to fix this problem

Comment: @RPD, yes, replace your query with the one in answer

Comment: Is working but I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer. Thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

You just need to change the select to:

```
var itemColl = from p in re.Kategorie 
    where p.Nazwa == category 
    select p.Id_kat;
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<int>` which is what you are trying to use in the `foreach`.

The `select new { p.Id_Kat }` is creating a new [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) which is in the simplest way of saying it is a new class like this:

```
class AnonymousType#1
{
    public int Id_Kat {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var itemColl = from p in re.Kategorie
               where p.Nazwa == category
               //This is Anonymous Type
               select new
               {
                  //Anonymous type's attribute(s) go(es) here 
                  IntItem = p.Id_kat
               };

               foreach (var s in itemColl)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine(s.IntItem);
               }
```

Comment: While this would solve the issue, creating a completely new type just to wrap an `int` is not advisable.

Comment: agreed...but just wanted to make the user aware of anonymous type & its properties

Comment: Absolutely. So explain it in text, I think OP would appreciate that? =)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could return a real (int)-value instead of an anonymous linq-result

```
var itemColl = from p in re.Kategorie
    where p.Nazwa == category
    select p.Id_Kat;
```

Comment: The first is incorrect; `s` is the anonymous type, not the integer; the second would work, though